# selenium webdriver error, gecko driver downloaded

Tags: firefox, selenium-webdriver

receiving the below error,i made sure i added the library for the webdriver
also started the standalone server from command prompt
 I am new to software testing, any help would be greatly appreciated

Firefox version 53

[image: selenium error]

Answer (score 0):

1. Make sure the absolute path you have provided for gecko driver is correct.
2. If we are going to launch the browser for the first time we should use get method instead of navigate as below.

   ```
   driver.get("http://www.calculator.net");
   ```

   Once you have launched the browser with url,using get method(as above eg..) you can use navigate.to to navigate to other url's
3. No need to start the selenium server from the command prompt. Just refer the selenium standalone jar to the build path of the java project.